# Find Missing Employees in Salary table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables which are as follows

```
`mysql> describe employees;
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| birth_date | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name | varchar(14)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name  | varchar(16)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gender     | enum('M','F') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hire_date  | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe salaries;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| salary    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| from_date | date    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| to_date   | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)`
```

Considering the fact that every employee must be salaried I expected the number of rows
In salaries table to be same as that in employees and hence all emp_no present in employee
to be also in salaries.But on execution of Count statement i see below result.

```
`mysql> select count(*) from employees;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   300024 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> select count(*) from salaries;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  2844047 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This shows that there are few person present in employees but missing in salaries so i did
below Query to find if there is any.

```
`mysql> select * from employees where emp_no not in (select emp_no from salaries) ;
 Empty set (0.96 sec)`
```

emp_no being primary key is unique, so why is there different number of rows in both tables,
even though the above result returns empty set when i queried it using not in .

I also found some same name in employee but with different hire_date but then emp_no 
was different for them.

```
 `mysql> select * from employees where first_name='Zvonko' and last_name='Perko';
 +--------+------------+------------+-----------+--------+------------+
 | emp_no | birth_date | first_name | last_name | gender | hire_date  |
 +--------+------------+------------+-----------+--------+------------+
 |  20909 | 1961-04-24 | Zvonko     | Perko     | F      | 1990-12-14 |
 | 488633 | 1961-08-01 | Zvonko     | Perko     | F      | 1995-08-08 |
 +--------+------------+------------+-----------+--------+------------+
```

Where am I going wrong ? Can someone let me know .

Comment: Aren't you, well, surprised by the sheer number of records in `salaries` table? )

Comment: I guess mistake on my part as I misread the number of rows in salaries . I guess I would like to close this Question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about It was misread by me and after reading it more precisiley it does not make sense to make such query.

Answer (score 1):

Your salary table has more rows than your employees table. About three million vs. about three hundred thousand.

The salary table has a two-part primary key, which means one employee might have multiple salaries with different from_dates. You know, for raises and stuff.

Comment: That's really hard to read in a comment. Put that in your question instead if it's relevant.

Comment: I guess mistake on my part as I misread the number of rows in salaries . I guess I would like to close this Question.